# Qty in cart always 1 for every product?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am running a **Magento 1.9.3.7** store with the Ultimo theme. No matter what I enter in the qty box on the product page, the number is always 1 ion the cart.

I debugged a little and figured that there is no qty in the request. Any ideas where to keep looking?

I looked at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` and there in the `addProduct` function. The `$requestInfo` object has no qty at all. When I change the qty in the cart it works as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: you might have to look into the form sending data to the controller.

Comment: I did, it has no qty either ... I looked at `addAction` in the CartController and there at `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`. No qty there...

Comment: That is why I was asking you to look into the post data sent to the controller by the form.

Comment: What do you mean, can you add some code please?

Comment: I meant the html form which is supposed to send post data to the controller, I can't really post a code as this maybe different for each theme.

Comment: it can be js as well, in  case the request sent to the controller is ajax.

Comment: I figured its theme related, after using the default theme it works. I also removed the addtocart.phtml from my theme in order to use the default one, but this did not change a ting. Any idea where to continue looking?